# How to show my cocoa touch framework storyboard screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I created a simple Cocoa touch framework with a storyboard. In my framework i have a MainViewController.swift viewcontroller.
I created a new single view project, imported my framework and  tried to load my framework viewcontroller, but i got black screen. And I dont know why.

I tried load framework with this code:

```
let frameworkScreen : UIViewController = MainViewController()
    self.presentViewController(frameworkScreen, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: The problem is that `MainViewController()` makes a view controller but does not tell this controller where to get its view from. So that view is empty and black. You say there is a storyboard in your framework, but you are not _using_ that storyboard.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i use my storyboard?

Comment: I'll show you, hang on a moment.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didnt find any solution for my problem..

Comment: Finished my answer. I think you'll find this solves it nicely, and I've tried to explain why.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to load the view controller by instantiating it *from the storyboard in the framework*.

Here's how. First some initial conditions:

- Let's say your framework is called Coolness.
- Let's say your framework's storyboard is called *CoolnessStoryboard.storyboard*.
- Let's say your framework has a `public` class called CoolnessViewController.
- Let's say that CoolnessStoryboard has a scene whose view controller is CoolnessViewController and that this is its *initial* view controller.

Then in your main code you would `import Coolness` and, to present your CoolnessViewController from the storyboard, you would say:

```
let s = UIStoryboard (
    name: "CoolnessStoryboard", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: CoolnessViewController.self)
)
let vc = s.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Note the strategy here. Work backwards from the goal. We need the instance of CoolnessViewController that is *in the storyboard*. To get that, we need a reference to that storyboard. To do that, we need to identify that storyboard. How? We can identify it by name and by the bundle that it is in. But how can we identify that bundle? We can identify the bundle by means of a class in that bundle. We *have* such a class, because we have imported the framework (`import Coolness`) and the class there is `public` (so we can speak of it).

Comment: So I tried your code, but i got this:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Storyboard' in bundle NSBundle...
My framework name is MyTestFramework (i imported this), my framework storyboard name is Storyboard.storyboard, and my framework viewcontroller is MainViewController

Comment: ohh, i found the solution! I had a navigation controller in my framework storyboard...

Comment: Right, my answer shows you the technique, but applying it to your specific situation is up to you! That is why I described my "initial conditions" so precisely.

Comment: It's working fine in `Xcode 13 & iOS 15`, and very nice explanation...

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. This is how I solved after a little research:

1 - I have a framework called "Messenger.framework"

2 - Inside it, I have a storyboard file called "Messenger.Storyboard"

3- My initial view controller is a UINavigationController with a rootViewController and my ChatController.

So this is how a present my framework's chat UIViewController:

```
- (void)presentChatController
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Messenger"
                                                         bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:ChatController.class]];

    ChatController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Chat"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: where to call this presentChatController ?I have called this method in viewDidAppear() but it get called multiple times.

Comment: You call it when you want to present the new controller. You can call it when user press a button for example.

Answer (score 4):

If your framework name is `MyFramework`, and storyboard name is `Main`, with a viewcontoller with storyboard id `vc`

```
if let urlString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyFramework", ofType: "framework", inDirectory: "Frameworks") {
  let bundle = (NSBundle(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlString)))
  let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: bundle)
  let vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc")
  self.showViewController(vc, sender: nil)
}
```

I have inculded the framework using cocoapods.

In **Swift 5.5, Xcode 13 and iOS 15**

```
if let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyFramework", ofType: "framework", inDirectory: "Frameworks") {
   let bundle = (Bundle(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlString) as URL))
   let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: bundle)
   let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc")
   self.show(vc, sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: I have problem with this approach. When I have custom class for "vc" It is not loaded :(