# How to embed/integrate a Vuforia Unity 2017.3 build OC iOS project into Swift iOS project as a framework

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I met some tutorial which introduces how to integrate legacy Unity exported iOS project into Objective-C iOS project.  Like: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PW7_CfIwY0

However, some of these tutorials are merge and hybrid two iOS projects into one, not a framework.

Is there a solution to integrate Unity build iOS project as a framework of a Swift iOS project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't export a Unity project as an iOS framework. Your only option is to do the following:

1. Use [this method](https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity) to integrate your Unity build into an iOS project as a subview (it works for 2017.3.0f3! tested it myself)
2. Create an iOS framework out of the `UIViewController` containing the Unity view (this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30288143/3551916) explains how to instantiate the VC from the framework)

That way, instead of getting a hybrid of two projects, it's one project integrated within the other as a framework

Comment: Demo project is not working for me ,i want to integrate unity build with swift project,can you help me.