# iOS how to start a viewcontroller from framework

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, xcode9

I have created my private framework successfully. It has no error. I have created a project now I want a simple thing but I do not have clue. Following is what I want

> I want to start the Framework view controller.
>   You can think it is the whole app. I want to start its first view
>   controller. and then the app flow is as per business logic. I
>   want to exit app when user exit the Framework main view controller. Actually it was the complete app but I decided to make it framework for different clients because only small modifications are needed for different clients but I do not know how it should be done.

here is how I am trying to start first view controller in my Client project but it does not recognize that controller.

```
 @IBAction func onClickBtnStartOver(_ sender: Any)
 {
     let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle:nil)            
     let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("idFrameworkVC") as FwViewController
     self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
 }
```

It gives me error like "***Use of undeclared type 'FwViewController'***"

So what should I do to start the  first viewcontroller of framework.

**Note: I have viewcontrollers in one Storyboard namely Storyboard inside Framework**

Comment: Did you declare your classes as public/open in your framework?

Comment: yes i did declare

Answer (score 2):

Declare an open func in your framework for opening first viewController :

```
open func presentFirstViewControllerOn(_ viewController:UIViewController) {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("idFrameworkVC") as FwViewController
    viewController.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

and call this method from client app's VC.
Deciding which is the first VC (if needed) should be the responsibility of the framework, not your client app.

Comment: can you please tell me how to change colors in the framework storyboard views from client app?

Comment: A framework should be a reusable component my friend. If you need to change colors every now and then, the I don't think creating a framework is the right thing because then the component doesn't seem to be reusable

Comment: So its mean that it can not be done in the IOS. whereas it can easily be done in the Android, by just oerriding same color names in colors.xml file and it just replaces it with the colors in the client app. So there is no need to change other coding and working of the app

Comment: but then how can i send data backwards through delegates from nextviewcontroller to viewcontroller?

Answer (score 2):

use your framework bundle identifier

```
 let frameworkBundle = Bundle(identifier: "your framework bundle identifier")
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "your framework storyboard name", bundle: frameworkBundle)
 let mas = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UIViewController
 self.present(mas, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
          UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController =  UIStoryboard(name: "yy", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything is setup nicely then you may have not imported your framework in it. This is very important part. Make double check if You have declared Public your framework VC. 
Then After it you need to start It in you method.

I will suggest to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287935/how-to-show-my-cocoa-touch-framework-storyboard-screen) selected answer. And this is the case with you

PS: Do not forget to go through into comments on the selected answer as there is discussion about crash. I doubted that you face them, But if you did encounter any crash then fix the issue using that comment in answer

Comment: Though I did not got the full answer , but for now I am accepting this answer

Answer (score 0):

In case if you don't want to make your view controller public/open , and still want to open it from client app ,here is the code.

Inside your private framework ,publicly extend the view controller and write function

```
public extension UIViewController {
func presentMyController() {
        let frameworkBundle = Bundle(identifier: "your framework bundle identifier")
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: frameworkBundle)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("idMyController") as MyController
        self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
}}
```

And in your client app

```
func onButtonClick(){
  self.presentMyController()
 }
```